# Autofac Dependency Resolution Exception

Tags: xamarin.forms

When I use a LinearGradientBrush (from the new 4.8 version of Xamarin.Forms), I get the followin error:

**Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: 'An exception was thrown while activating App.Modules.Loading.LoadingView.'**

In the page preview in Visual Studio, it shows the page as expected. When I comment the LinearGradientBrush block, it runs fine.

Do you have any idea why this happens?

Thank you!

Best regards,

Eduardo Luczinski.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App.Modules.Loading.LoadingView">

    <ContentPage.Background>

        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                             EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Color="#3B8476"
                          Offset="0.1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#00352B"
                          Offset="1.0"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

    </ContentPage.Background>

    <ContentPage.Content>


        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">


            <ProgressBar  x:Name="loadingBar" VerticalOptions="End" ProgressColor="#FFFF" Progress="0.25"/>

        </StackLayout>


    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Show us the code behind and/or the viewmodel, I don't think this it's related to any xaml UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to enable LinearGradientBrush in ContentPage, according to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/internals/experimental-flags),you need to set up experimental flags in your target platforms projects.

On android  in your `MainActivity` class, on ios in `AppDelegate` Class:

```
 Forms.SetFlags("Brush_Experimental");
```

Making sure to call SetFlags() before Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init()

The there is no problem, and it works fine.

Comment: That solved the issue! Thank you very much!